# Recursive query with two tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server, recursion, parent-child

I have two tables and I want to do a recursive query in order to get a final table with a parent-child relationship and a column saying if it has childs. My idea was to join both tables and use a use CTE (the query give me an error I attach it) and an image of what I want to do.

**DESCRIPTION**
Table 1 and 2 show us the states of an Account and Operation, table 1 has all "Product" 999 and table 2 has all  "Product" 39. The main idea of this, is to look up for the origen of the Account and Operation with "Product"999 in table 1, for example:

In table 1,

- First, the row with Product_Ini = 999 / Acccount_Ini = 777 / Operation_Ini = 888 came from Product_Fin = 999 / Acccount_Fin = 777 / Operation_Fin = 666
- Second, the idea is to look up for the origen of Product_Fin = 999 / Acccount_Fin = 777 / Operation_Fin = 666, in order to do this i do a CTE in the same table and i find Product_Fin = 39 / Acccount_Fin = 126/ Operation_Fin = 333
- Third, the idea is to look up for the origen of Product_Fin = 39/ Acccount_Fin = 126 / Operation_Fin = 333, in order to do this i have to use table 2 and search there, having the result Product_Fin = 32 / Acccount_Fin = 126/ Operation_Fin = 858
- Finally, i want to get a table showing the evolution of an account, with a column Child that means if the account/operation has childs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**QUERY:**

```
drop table #table_1
go
create table #table_1
(
    Product_Ini int,
    Account_Ini int,
    Operation_Ini   int,
    Product_Fin int,
    Account_Fin int,
    Operation_Fin int
)
go

drop table #table_2
go
create table #table_2
(
    Product_Ini int,
    Account_Ini int,
    Operation_Ini   int,
    Product_Fin int,
    Account_Fin int,
    Operation_Fin int
)
go

insert into #table_1 values (999, 123, 456, 32  ,123, 426)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 123, 456, 23  ,123, 159)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 123, 456, 65  ,123, 486)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 596, 162, 32  ,596, 263)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 529, 999 ,126, 459)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 459, 32  ,126, 784)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 741, 999 ,126, 852)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 852, 999 ,126, 111)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 111, 999 ,126, 333)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 126, 333, 32  ,126, 995)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 523, 542, 999 ,523, 478)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 777, 888, 999 ,777, 666)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 777, 666, 39  ,126, 333)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 899, 565, 39  ,899, 474)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 565, 145, 39  ,565, 424)
insert into #table_1 values (999, 565, 361, 85  ,565, 452)
----
insert into #table_2 values (39, 126, 333, 32   ,126, 858)
insert into #table_2 values (39, 899, 474, 999  ,899, 525)
insert into #table_2 values (39, 565, 424, 999  ,565, 361)
--

select * from #table_1
select * from #table_2

;WITH ctetable(depth, Product_Ini, Account_Ini, Operation_Ini, Product_Fin, Account_Fin, Operation_Fin) as 
(
    SELECT 1 as depth, Product_Ini, Account_Ini, Operation_Ini, Product_Fin, Account_Fin, Operation_Fin
    FROM #table_1 as a 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.depth + 1 AS depth, b.Product_Ini, b.Account_Ini, b.Operation_Ini, c.Product_Fin, c.Account_Fin, c.Operation_Fin
    FROM ctetable AS b JOIN #table_1 as c on c.Product_Ini = b.Product_Fin and c.Account_Ini = b.Account_Fin and c.Operation_Ini = b.Operation_Fin
)
SELECT * 
--INTO #TMP_FINAL
FROM CTETABLE 
order by Account_Ini, Operation_Ini
GO
```

**TABLES** 
[image]

Comment: Great job posting ddl and sample data. Can you explain the output? I don't understand the column "Childs". What is that showing? And I don't really understand the relationship between the two tables. For example, there are two rows in table one with Account_ini of 777 but there are 3 rows in the output. Where does that third row come from? That new row just materialized but no clue why.

Comment: @EGSL, you have done a good job asking the question with detailed data and expected result, if you can provide some info about the relationship of #table_1 and #table_2, that may give us better ideas what are after.

Comment: @SeanLange i added some details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jyao i added some details. Thanks in advance.